# Error returning JSON from A.P.I request in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am beginning my first angular.js app. I have written code to call a spanish rhyming dictionary A.P.I. In this code I log the JSON response to the console. However there is an error when I run this code. The console doesn't give me the specific error but it concerns my app.js file

Here is the website for the A.P.I-

[Rhyme Searcher](https://store.apicultur.com/apis/info?name=BuscadorDeRimas&version=1.0.0&provider=MolinodeIdeas)

Here is the repository with my code: https://github.com/Renniesb/rap_in_a_box

Here is my app.js code:

```
var rhymeApp = angular.module('rhymeApp', ['ngResource']);

rhymeApp.controller('rhymeView', function ($scope, $resource) {

$scope.rhymeApi = 
$resource("http://store.apicultur.com/api/rima/1.0.0/flor/true/0/200/true",
{callBack: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, { get: {method: "JSONP"}});

$scope.rhymeResult = $scope.rhymeApi.get();

console.log($scope.rhymeResult);
});
```

Comment: What is the error logged? No one will go through random code for you...

Comment: It doesn't give me specifics it just says the following: 
angular.js:9145 GET http://store.apicultur.com/api/rima/1.0.0/flor/true/0/200/true?callBack=angular.callbacks._0 f @ angular.js:9145(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9001t @ angular.js:8862f @ angular.js:8582(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12222k.$eval @ angular.js:13424k.$digest @ angular.js:13236k.$apply @ angular.js:13528(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1493e @ angular.js:4122d @ angular.js:1491hc @ angular.js:1511xd @ angular.js:1405(anonymous function) @ angular.js:24633a @ angular.js:2725Xe.c @ angular.js:2996

Comment: Your being mean, I told you in the description that it does not give me a specific error message. You don't need to downvote me for that, it is not my fault.

Comment: It does say that the problem with angular.js line 9145

Comment: Line 9145 in angular.js is- rawDocument.body.appendChild(script);

Answer (score 2):

`$resource.get()` is asynchronous which means that you need to provide a callback function to process the API response. Try using

```
$scope.rhymeApi.get({}, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: You need to have proper authentication to use the API

Comment: Ok, One more question. How do I incorporate the authentication token into angular.js $resource service?

Comment: Depends. If it's passed through header then you can pass it via 
`get: { method: 'GET', headers : { 'auth-key' : 'key' }}`